# nginx block direct access to url but allow embedding from whitelisted domains

Tags: nginx, dns, whitelist

I'm about to set up my own livestreaming server (running nginx and owncast) and would like to prevent direct access to the stream url but allow embedding the url in a whitelisted domain (another website where I deal with user management and payment stuff). Much like vimeo does, where I can restrict the access to videos and livestreams to whitelisted domains. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best bet is by using the Content Security Policy "frame-ancestors" directive.

You can tell nginx to add this additional header.

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'mycustomsite.com';";
```

You can find some additional examples of this CSP directive here: https://content-security-policy.com/frame-ancestors/

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but since this approach is browser-dependent (_"The frame-ancestors CSP directive is not supported at all in Internet Explorer"_) it's not secure enough. Anyone using a tool that doesn't evaluate this feature has access, right?